# JavaScript: why doesn't this simple animation test work?

Tags: javascript, animation

```
<p id="test">Test</p>
<button onclick="move(getElementById(" test "))">click me</button>

function move(elem) {
    var lft = 0;

    function anim() {
        lft++
            elem.style.left = lft + "px";
        if (lft == 100) {clearInterval(myVal);}

        }

    var myVal = setInterval(function(){anim()}, 500);

    }
```

I'm just trying to get the "Test" text to move across the screen. This doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/qfovLayv/2/

Comment: you should check the error you are getting on the console. (hint you have two errors)

Comment: Alas I don't know how to do this. Is this possible on JSfiddle? (That's the only resource I have currently).

Answer (score 2):

The `left` property only applies to *positioned elements*.

A positioned element is on where the value of the `position` property is something other than `static`.

`static` is the default value and you haven't changed it.

Set `position` to `fixed`, `relative`, or `absolute` depending on what you actually want.

---

Additionally, if you are using a `"` to mark the start an end of an attribute value, then the next `"` will end the attribute value.

```
onclick="move(getElementById("
```

If you want to use a `"` character as data in such a value, you must use a character reference: "

You could use `'` instead.

---

Additionally, your ID doesn't have any spaces in it, so you shouldn't have any spaces in the string you pass to `getElementById`.

Comment: Thanks, rookie mistake, but still doesn't seem to work for me :(

http://jsfiddle.net/qfovLayv/3/   <updated

I'm guessing that there might be something wrong with the way I call the function with my button